# How do I change the size of my input box for my login form?

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy, kivy-language

I am creating a login page for an app I am creating for a school project. The GUI so far looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRxOO.png). I have been trying to change the x size of username and password text input fields in my code. So far I have tried to change the size_hint_x of the box layout that the username and password text inputs are in to none and then set it manually, which makes it bigger but off-centres it. No matter what numbers i put in i did not know how to change the x value while keeping it centred. I would like it to be half the size of the whole screen, and centred.

Any advice or solutions would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the .py file

```py
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window


class LogInWindow(BoxLayout):  # creating LogInWindow class
    kv = Builder.load_file("my.kv")  # loading the kivy file which has all the

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def validate_user(self):  # creating a function to validate the user
        username_input_kivy = self.ids.username_field  # setting the input to a variable
        password_input_kivy = self.ids.password_field  # setting the input to a variable
        info = self.ids.info  # setting the input to a variable

        username_input = username_input_kivy.text  # getting the text from an inout and putting it into a variable
        password_input = password_input_kivy.text  # getting the text from an inout and putting it into a variable

        if username_input == '' or password_input == '':  # checking if the fields are empty
            info.text = '[color=#FF0000]Username and / or Password Required[/color]'  # red error message
        else:
            if username_input == 'admin' and password_input == 'admin':  # checking if they are correct
                info.text = '[color=#00FF00]Logged In successfully!!![/color]'  # green success message
            else:
                info.text = '[color=#FF0000]Invalid Username and/or Password[/color]'  # red error message


class FitnessApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Window.size = (1080, 720)
        return LogInWindow()


if __name__ == '__main__':  # The value of __name__ attribute is set to “__main__” when module is run as main program
    FitnessApp = FitnessApp()
    FitnessApp.run()
```

And here is the .kv file (the place i am having trouble is teh second box layout)

```
<FlatButton@ButtonBehavior+Label>:
    font_size: 16  ## set font size

<LogInWindow>:
    id: Login_window
    orientation: "vertical"
    spacing: 10
    space_x: self.size[0]/3
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (1,1,1, 1)
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos

    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 100
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: (0, 0, 0, 1)
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
        Label:
            text: "Login"
            font_size: 48
            bold: True
            size_hint_x: .9
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        padding: Login_window.space_x, 10
        #spacing: 20
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            spacing: 10
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 125
            Label:
                id: info
                text: ''
                markup: True
                size_hint_y: None
                height: 20
            TextInput:
                id: username_field
                size_hint_x: 1
                hint_text: "Username"
                font_size: 24
                multiline: False
                focus: True
                on_text_validate: password_field.focus = True
            TextInput:
                id: password_field
                hint_text: "Password"
                font_size: 24
                multiline: False
                password: True
                on_text_validate: root.validate_user()
        Label:
            id: sp
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 40
        Button:
            text: "Sign In"
            font_size:24
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 40
            background_color: (0, 0, 0, 1)
            background_normal: ''
            on_release: root.validate_user()
        Label:
            id: sp2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The size of your `Username` and `Password` `TextInputs` are set by the size of the containing `BoxLayout` and its `padding`. In your code the padding is set by:

```
padding: Login_window.space_x, 10
```

This references `Login_window.space_x` which is defined by:

```
space_x: self.size[0]/3
```

in the `<LogInWindow>` rule. So the horizontal padding is set to one third the width of the `LogInWindow`. With 1/3 padding on each side, the `TextInputs` fill the remaining third. To get the `TextInputs` width to half the window with, just make the padding a quarter of the window width, like this:

```
space_x: self.size[0]/4
```